# How to turn off droput during validation/tesing phase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, spyder, dropout

I'm new in neural network. I know that during the validation/testing time the dropout must be to turn off because dropout makes neurons output 'wrong' values on purpose. So it is better in order to have a good result in term of accuracy. 
How can I do it in my code? THe dataset is composed by 18 features, 1 label and it is a regression problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from keras.regularizers import l2

# =============================================================================
# Scelgo il test size
# =============================================================================
test_size = 0.2

dataset = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv', decimal=',', delimiter = ";")

label = dataset.iloc[:,-1]
features = dataset.drop(columns = ['Label'])

y_max_pre_normalize = max(label)
y_min_pre_normalize = min(label)

def denormalize(y):
    final_value = y*(y_max_pre_normalize-y_min_pre_normalize)+y_min_pre_normalize
    return final_value

# =============================================================================
# Split
# =============================================================================

X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, label, test_size = test_size, shuffle = True)

y_test2 = y_test1.to_frame()
y_train2 = y_train1.to_frame()

# =============================================================================
# Normalizzo
# =============================================================================
scaler1 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)
X_test = scaler2.fit_transform(X_test1)


scaler3 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler4 = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_train = scaler3.fit_transform(y_train2)
y_test = scaler4.fit_transform(y_test2)



# =============================================================================
# Creo la rete
# =============================================================================
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(60, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'linear',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100,
                    validation_split = 0.1, shuffle=True, batch_size=250
                    )

history_dict = history.history

loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']

y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_train_pred = denormalize(y_train_pred)
y_test_pred = denormalize(y_test_pred)


plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_test1),(y_test_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Test')

plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_train1),(y_train_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Train')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(loss_values,'b',label = 'training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label = 'val training loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss Function')
plt.legend()

print("\n\nThe R2 score on the test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test_pred, y_test1)))

print("The R2 score on the train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train_pred, y_train1)))
from sklearn import metrics

# Measure MSE error.  
score = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1)
print("\n\nFinal score test (MSE): %0.4f" %(score))
score1 = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1)
print("Final score train (MSE): %0.4f" %(score1))
score2 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test_pred,y_test1))
print(f"Final score test (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score2))
score3 = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train_pred,y_train1))
print(f"Final score train (RMSE): %0.4f" %(score3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with accepted answer, but I want to add one thing. When you use dropout during training with rate lets say 10%, then around 10% of your neurons will be cut off. During test phase you have all your neurons back, but layer activation will be scaled with 0.9(10% loss). Because layer response should be similar as it was during training phase.

Comment: so there is a kind of simulation (let me say) of the dropout also in test phase?

Comment: Yes is possible to say this. This scaling is related to statistic of layer, if you during training drop 10% of layer nodes is possible consider that layer response will be 10% lower.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow, Keras and other deep learning libraries takes care of it behind the scene. One doesn't have to explicilty remove dropout for inference. The dropout would be effective only in training phase.
Also, dropout just drops out neurons, along with incoming and outgoing connections, randomly in the respective layer on every iteration. And the purpose is to avoid overfitting. It has nothing to do with correct or wrong output of layers.